# How to create a String Array with additional characters?

Tags: java

How is it possible to create a String array with some special characters like `Ö`, `ä`, `Ü` and so on.

That is very important for me since UTF 8 encoding. Now this solution with a String Array directly in java code causes a error:

```
String[] invalidCharacters = { "!", "\"", "§", "%", "&", "/", "\\", "{", "}", "[", "]",
        "(", ")", "`", "´", "'", "²", "µ", "#", "+", "~", ",", ";", ":", "_", "<", ">", ".",
        "|", "@", "^", "°", "ü", "Ü", "ä", "Ä", "ö", "Ö", "ß", "Ø", "ø", "å", "æ", "Æ" };
```

I get the error "unmappable character for encoding UTF8"

Is the only way to work with an external file and read the content of this file?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: This will need some more context and/or explanation because it is really vague...

Comment: You can always use Unicode notation: `String[] unicodeCharacters = { "\u00ea" , "\u00f1" , "\u00fc" }`. Not that this solves any issue, just to let you know.

Comment: Are you sure your IDE is properly treating your code as UTF-8?

Comment: So far, you have posted 42 questions, most of this have 1 or more answers. You are free to accept none, if you want. But I think you should accept some of them and finally get the scholar badge :)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler assumes your input (Source file) is encoded with UTF-8, make sure your editor (Eclipse, Netbeans..) saves the file with UTF-8 and not any other encoding.

Comment: @Henry How is that opposing what I said?

Comment: @MarounMaroun you said the compiler assumes UTF-8, the platform encoding may or may not be UTF-8

Comment: @Henry I was referring his case :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two options: you can directly put the characters into the file as you did, but then the encoding of the file must match the encoding used by the compiler (see the `-encoding` option of the compiler).

The other way is to use unicode escapes like `\u00f6` for `ö`.